# Password type textbox in alert dialog

Tags: android

How can I make textbox here to be a password type? I'm using the code below but it doesn't work.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

alert.setTitle("Verification");
alert.setMessage("Enter your Verification Code");
alert.setCancelable(false);
final EditText encrypt = new EditText(getActivity());
encrypt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
alert.setView(encrypt);
alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
```

Comment: what exactly does not work? Isn´t it a passwort inputType or is the view not appearing in the dialog?

Comment: well the textbox is appearing, but it doesnt encrypt the words i type there into password like, just a plane readable text is appearing sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
encrypt.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 2):

If this should be a password input view, You should set it like this:

```
  encrypt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```